# Is there a safe way of embedding iframe in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, security, iframe, websecurity

the only way to set iframe url is by doing `this.domsanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)`. But static code analysis tools like veracode raises this as an high vulnerability issue which i think is correct. But is there a way to safely trust the url like whitelisiting the url?

Answer (score 1):

An iframe is always a security risk if you are not controlling its content. There is simply no way to have an iframe in your page without "bypassing" some sanitization process and trusting the resource.

Maybe you can implement your own [sanitizer](https://angular.io/api/core/Sanitizer) and sanitize method for your custom needs if the content of the url is something you can precisely assume what it is to be. This would be more secure than just trusting it and the analysis tool would be ok with this too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [sandbox attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) in the iframe.

Comment: sandboxing is actually the same thing with sanitizing it unless you allow some content like scripts etc. and this would be the same with bypassing the sanitization in Angular